# my absence function dosnt work properly pgsql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-function

Hey I wanted to create a function that adds absences to the student if he has 3 absence in one material that mean his eliminated I wanted to create a function that adds absent and he reached 3 absences that mean his eliminated but the problem that when I try the function it doesn't add to the previous table but it create another row

```
CREATE TABLE abssance (
  id_abssance     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  id_etudiant int,
    id_matiere int,
    abss int,
  eliminé  int
);
```

```
  create or replace function test2(etudiant int, matiere int, abssancee int) 
    RETURNs int as 
    $$ 
    begin 
     update  abssance set id_etudiant=etudiant,id_matiere=matiere, abss= abssancee + 1 where abss > 2;
    if abssancee=3  
    then 
      update abssance set eliminé=1 ;
      return 1;
    else 
     return 0; 
    end if; 
    end $$ 
    language plpgsql;
```

Always returns 0 doesn't add another value in the actual row that I wanna updated it

resault that i get is this
[image]

But I wanted it like this 
[image]
and if the abss= 3 it will add 1 on the eliminé

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: i update it  as u said

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause of the update sounds wrong. Logically, you don't want to update ALL rows having 2 absences, but rather to update ONE row for the given student/course

```
update  abssance 
set abss= abssancee + 1 
WHERE id_etudiant=etudiant AND id_matiere=matiere;
```

Similarly, the update for `elimine` is missing the `where` clause to update the proper student

```
update abssance 
set eliminé=1 
WHERE id_etudiant=etudiant;
```

Comment: after i did like u told me i don't know but it only worked on one then after i insert another id it dosnt add or showed in the abssence database and still add another row instead of update the acutel row

Comment: There is no insert in your code... Something else inserting instead of updating